# What is the most reliable way to check if a successful MySQL query has returned no results?

Tags: php, mysql, isset, mysql-num-rows

I want to check if a successful query has returned no results.

When testing this script locally, I make sure that the database does not contain any values the query is seeking, but

```
mysqli_num_rows($res) != 0
```

returns true.

```
mysqli_num_rows($res)
```

returns the integer 1, and

```
echo json_encode($res)
```

returns

```
{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}
```

**script.php**

```
$sql    = "SELECT AVG(numUsers) FROM attendance 
           WHERE date = '".$currDate."' 
           AND HOUR(time) = '".$currTime."' ";

$res    = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)or die(mysqli_error($conn));

if(mysqli_num_rows($res) != 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        $numUsers = $row['AVG(numUsers)'];
    }
    // Round this average value to the nearest integer
    $numUsers = round($numUsers);
}else{
    echo "No values have yet been inserted into 'attendance' during the current hour.";
}

// Insert $numUsers into another table
```

What this means is that once this result array is returned, the *numUsers* variable remains empty, and

```
round($numUsers)
```

returns zero, which is an illegitimate value that is later inserted into the database.

How can I most reliably check that the successful query has returned a valid result, and that *numUsers* has been set accordingly?

Comment: Use an alias `SELECT AVG(numUsers) as avgusers ...` to make the code a little easier to work with So you can use `$row['avgusers']`

Comment: Only as note `SELECT AVG(numUsers)` will allways have an result, maybe nothing is calulated, but it returns a value (e.g. NULL). And it will always be one result row.

Comment: I'd think that this query will always return 1 row even if the content is `NULL` so strict check if the result is null (e.g. `$row['AVG(numUsers)'] !== null` instead of num_rows).

Comment: As you will only ever get ONE ROW returned you also dont need the WHILE loop

Comment: You could also do all that in SQL by doing `SELECT ROUND(AVG(numUsers)) as avgusers FROM attendance .....`